# How effective were starfighters in the dominion war? I didn't watch deep space 9

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Were starfighter-type ships effective in the dominion war? All I've seen were clips of battles, as I can't find the time to watch deep space nine, and I don't really see how effective they are, as most clips I find are simple flyby strafing runs.

Comment: Possible dupe of [Why aren't there any fighter carriers in the Star Trek universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5991/why-arent-there-any-fighter-carriers-in-the-star-trek-universe)

Comment: What “starfighter-type ships” are you thinking of?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - One can only assume these: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_attack_fighter

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was the Klingons who did most of the "heavy lifting" holding ground by battling on the front lines toward the end of the war. In all the Star Trek series, Earth was always about exploration and peace, so their ships and weaponry tended to be primarily built for defense, not war; unlike the Klingons. Plus, I think the Klingons had around 2-3 times the number of ships as Earth during the war. Ultimately, the Federation Alliance won.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Official Star Trek Fact Files, the [Federation Attack Fighter](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_attack_fighter) is a formidable and highly adaptable ship-type, especially against smaller fleet ships. They have a powerful phaser and can also deploy photon (and latterly quantum) torpedoes in surgical strikes against shield weaknesses.

> **Combat capability:**
> By the time of the Dominion
> War, **the [Federation Attack Fighter] has proved to
> be highly adaptable in interstellar
> dogfights,** and in attack raids
> against Dominion/Cardassian
> flotillas. **The fighters have been a
> key element in fleet tactics since
> the onset of the war**, but they
> perhaps play their most famous
> role to date during Operation
> Retrieve, the mission to retake
> Deep Space Nine
> Deployed in flights of four to
> eight craft, the fighters scare
> away the more temperamental
> Cardassian pilots, and open a hole
> in Dominion lines that the larger
> Starfleet ships can exploit.
>
> **STARFLEET ATTACK FIGHTERS**
> are **a formidable
> force in battle,**
> despite their size,
> and are **among
> Starfleet's most
> hard-wearing and
> adaptable battle
> craft.** They will
> typically form part
> of a much larger
> attack fleet.
>
> <sub><sup>[Official Star Trek Fact Files: File 31, Card #21 - "*Starfleet Attack Fighters*"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Fact_Files)</sup></sub>